# On `dpkg -i` a package to refer the dependency other than found dependencies in a dir

Tags: dependencies, debian

How on Debian do we tell on `dpkg -i`  a package to get the dependency other than found dependencies in a certain location ?   e.g:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i foobar_99_amd64.deb

(Reading database ... 355213 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack foobar_99_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking foobar_99 ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of foobar:
 foobar depends on python3 (>= 3.9~); however:
  Version of python3 on system is 3.7.3-1.
 foobar depends on libc6 (>= 2.29); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.28-10.
 foobar depends on libocct-foundation-7.5 (>= 7.5.1+dfsg1); however:
  Package libocct-foundation-7.5 is not installed.
```

These three has been prepared in a dir., e.g., /baz

So how definitively solving it for foobar or another else package whenever some its depedencies are not ready on mainstream dir. but really are in the prepared one ?

Comment: I do not understand. `dpkg -i` never install dependencies, you should do it manually `dpkg -i foo.deb bar.deb spam.deb ...`. `dpkg` is just the low level tool, you should used other tools to automatically install packages

Answer (score 0):

apt command-line package manager will install the dependencies of a .deb file automatically if it can find the dependency packages in your Debian's software sources as it frequently can. If apt can't find all the dependency packages, apt will print an error message showing which missing dependency packages need to be (manually) installed.

Change directories using `cd` to the directory containing foobar_99_amd64.deb and run the following command.

```
sudo apt install ./foobar_99_amd64.deb
```